# Alternative to MSMQ for windows server core

Tags: msmq, windows-server

I have a program that writes to a local MSMQ, and a customer that wants to install that program on Windows Server Core 2012, which I have just discovered does not support MSMQ.

Are there any alternative queueing technologies that will work on Windows Server Core 2012?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The only solution I can think of is move the queues into Azure as service bus queues. Then you should be able to send and receive messages that way.

Comment: I was contemplating using something like ravenDB to be able to queue internally with the need for outbound connectivity. It's not the perfect tool for the job, but it could be made to fulfill the role with a bit of hacking.

Comment: That would work - good call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked a Windows 2012 R2 Core server and MSMQ was fully available:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name MSMQ*
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                           Available
[ ] Services Message Queuing                        MSMQ-Services                  Available
    [ ] Serveur Message Queuing                     MSMQ-Server                    Available
    [ ] Déclencheurs Message Queuing                MSMQ-Triggers                  Available
    [ ] Intégration du service d’annuaire           MSMQ-Directory                 Available
    [ ] Prise en charge de la multidiffusion        MSMQ-Multicasting                Removed
    [ ] Prise en charge HTTP                        MSMQ-HTTP-Support              Available
    [ ] Service de routage                          MSMQ-Routing                   Available
[ ] Proxy DCOM Message Queuing                      MSMQ-DCOM                      Available
```

So I believe the data you've found of it not being available date back to Server 2008. (or it may be a difference between 2012 and 2012 R2 - unlikely, but in that case your solution is simple: upgrade!)

If you still want alternatives... well, in any way you'll have to change your code, as there are no other brokers that implement the MSMQ APIs. So either use a remote MSMQ, or change your broker altogether. For example, I can vouch for RabbbitMQ working on 2008R2 et 2012R2 server core. But it is just an example, and you will have to do a lot of refactoring to change the API.